# ACL user roles in Parse

Tags: android, database-design, data-structures, parse-platform, acl

I need help with ACL roles in Android app I'm building.

I'm building app in parse where the user can create a group and invite other users. User can't see the group or the content within it before he's invited. The creator can then invite users and then they can contribut content to that group. The admin can then promote regular users to admins so they can add/remove users and edit the content from everyone in the group.

I need some good infrastructure to manage the user roles that I can apply to the ACL. For example how can I create specific admin role-group for each group.

Here is how I'm managing the relation between the user and the group. A object with pointer to both user and the group the user is in (User-Group).

Example:
[image]

I have two groups. User A is admin in group 1 and user B is admin in group 2. If I assign 'admin' role to both A and B both of them can edit group 1 and group 2 but I only want them to be able to edit the group they are admin in.